# WPF : Send KeyCode to Active Application

Tags: .net, wpf

In my application I am building a onscreen keyboard where the individual keys would be WPF buttons. I want to send the corresponding Virtual Keycode(for each button) to the OS.

e.g I have a button in my application with content as 'A'. If I click on it, it should send virtual keycode 'A' to OS and 'A' should be added to the focused text box of the active application, just like hardware keyboard.

I want to is there any class and method which I can use to do so. I tried with SendKeys.SendWait("{A}"); but it does not work in WPF.

Comment: SendKeys.SendWait should work, how are you changing your focus to the application you are trying to send input to, Your WPF Keyboard will be the active application at the time you click a key.

Answer (score 4):

To expound on my comment [`SendKeys.SendWait`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.sendwait.aspx) will work with WPF whereas [`SendKeys.Send`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send.aspx) will not.  One of your problems is that if you are trying to send an A to another application you have the wrong format the Braces signify that it is a special key which for the letter A does not exist. You  need to use `SendKeys.SendWait("A")` instead.  The other issue is that if you are using your Wpf application as a Keyboard it is the foreground application at the time you click the button. You will need to delve into the WinApi and Pinvoke a couple of functions, namely [`FindWindow`](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/FindWindow.html) and [`SetForegroundWindow`](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SetForegroundWindow.html).

From link on SendKeys.Send:

> Because there is no managed method to activate another application, you can either use this class within the current application or use native Windows methods, such as FindWindow and SetForegroundWindow, to force focus on other applications.

**Sample showing how to switch to another application (*I am using Notepad as an example*)**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint="FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr ZeroOnly, string lpWindowName);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SetForegroundWindow(FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, "Untitled - Notepad"));
        SendKeys.SendWait("A");
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree re locating/focusing the window - but why the difference with making a synchronous call instead of an asynchronous one? Also, I'm not sure how it's implemented by the stock windows on-screen keyboard but it somehow seems to avoid focus yet remain topmost. I'm not sure if it switches focus back after every key or has some interesting window flags?

Comment: @Basic unfortunately the Send Method is not supported in Wpf, you can use other methods at a lower level such as WinApi's `PostMessage` and `SendMessage`

Comment: @Mark Hall - Thanks for the post. I have one more query. If I want the Keyboard to be embedded in a application and use the keyboard to send key codes to that case what approach should I take.

Now if I try to use the keyboard in a textbox in the same application then, after I click on the button, the textbox looses focus and it is not reflected. Kindly help.

Comment: To add to my previous comment, How can I find the focussed element and keep focus on it while the click event is fired. I guess this is the root to this problem.

Comment: @user2185985 If you are using the keyboard in the same application you will be able to handle your input and send it to the proper element. If you are looking to make your WPF application able to handle input from SendKeys you will need to add a WinProc to it as this article shows http://zamjad.wordpress.com/2009/09/10/accessing-windows-procedure-in-wpf-application/. If you are trying to find a specific element on another program you will need to use Spy and determine what the window name of the element is using FindwindoxEx.